# cloudera-scm-agent fails when using python 2.7

Tags: python, centos, cloudera-manager

Not sure how I can get around this...on the cloudera-manager site it says their software requires either pyhton2.6 or python2.7

however when i try to start the cloudera-scm-agent it complains that:

```
/opt/versioned_apps/cm-4.8.2/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm running centos7 (which is not supported out of the box).

To make matters worst, I don't know anything about python either (sorry)...so if i need to install anything, please provide step-by-step instructions :-)